# Year function in Google Sheets gives unexpected results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

Quick questions with Google Sheets.

I'm trying to extract the year from a date using the `YEAR()` function.
In the first column, I formatted all cells as dates, but in the second column, when I use `=YEAR()` and reference the first column I get really unexpected results.

[image: Says we're all the way back to 1905]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason is that column is *also* formatted as a *date*. Format it as a *number* and you'll get what you're after.

Google Sheets stores dates as a number of days from 12/31/1899. Your `YEAR()` is appropriately pulling out "2010" (for example) but is then converting it to a date. 2010 days after 12/31/1899 is 7/2/1905. (The big clue is that the two sample rows you show are seven years apart in the first column, then 7 *days* apart in the second column.)